# ansible ssh error Unreachable

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x

> UNREACHABLE!  changed : false , msg:SSH error:data could not be sent
>   to the remote host. Make sure this host can be reached over ssh",
>   "unreachable": true

**Hosts:**

```
[test]
xxxxxx.local ansible_ssh_user=myname
```

**ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False

[ssh_connection]
pipelining=true
```

I am running the playbook from Jenkins using execute shell `

Comment: What is the question? And did you follow the instructions given in the message you pasted here?

Comment: Getting error when running the playbook    -->  UNREACHABLE! 
changed : false , msg:SSH error:data could not be sent to the remote host.
Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true

Comment: Is there any cfg file I need to change ?

Comment: Of course you need change some configuration files. How does Ansible know where you store your SSH key? Which command do you use to run ansible-playbook. Does it contain --private-key option? Can you connect to instance manually?

Answer (score 0):

Your question need little bit more information about your environment or command used to run playbook. Although, you can try add to your `~/.ansible.cfg` file these lines, which may solve your issue

```
[ssh_connection]
control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r
```

Comment: so i will be installing ansible in virtual env  as "pip install ansible", then I run the ansible-playbook -i hosts playbooks/app.yml. @peterSmith

Comment: what directory we need to use in here " control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r "

Comment: to install Ansible you can use one of the options specified in http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html . Ansible configuration file (ansible.cfg) may be stored in your current working directory, or in your home directory as .ansible.cfg (as I wrote in the answer), or you can store your configuration in /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg. All option are here http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html after list of topics. Processing order is also mentioned in link.